# Programmatic Load Testing?-- outside Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, performance, load-testing

I was just wondering if there is a FREE framework I can use to **programmatically** run **WCF** load tests **outside** of Visual Studio.  I've seen that NUnit provides such functionality for unit testing, but can you do load testing with it?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Check out [WCF Load Test](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

2 Java based solutions are [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) and [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). If you doing strictly HTTP based testing one of these could work for you. JMeter is an app, not a framework, but it can be driven by XML. The Grinder is an api that requires Jython, so you would need to know or learn Python.

I have tried both of these and found them to be industrial strength solutions with steep learning curves. In the end, I convinced my company to buy Visual Studio Ultimate because that is what I know.